# Is StreamTableEnvironment able to run against batch stream?

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/

It says:

> Currently, the StreamTableEnvironment does not support enabling the
> batch execution mode yet. Nevertheless, bounded streams can be
> processed there using the streaming execution mode but with lower
> efficiency.

Does it mean that StreamTableEnvironment can work with batch stream but with lower effiency since the StreamTableEnvironment can't be configured to run in batch mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every stream processor can also process a stream that ends at some point.

However, batch mode makes the processing smarter. For example, the first operator consumes all data before and the second operator will start after the first finished. Instead of producing a row-wise result for every incoming row, the runtime will emit one batch of rows after the last operator finished.

So bounded stream processing is possible and in Flink 1.14 you will not see updates but only a final result being emitted from the runtime after enabling batch mode.

For further insights see also:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=158873744#content/view/158871522